# c# Linq Chain with avoid null exeption

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

i have multi tables with one to many relation like chain

1- address has postal code id

2- postal table has area id

3- area table has city id

4- city table has county id

5- county table has country id

6- and at the last country table

from every table i need to get street name , full postal code, area name , city name, county name , country name

the query is as follow

```
var address = from add in _Database.Addresses
                      select add;

        address.Select(x=>new AddressClass { 
        BuildingNameOrNumber=x.BuildingNameOrNumber,
        MainStreet = x.Postcode ==null ? string.Empty: x.Postcode.StreetName,
        FullPostCode = x.Postcode == null ?  string.Empty :x.Postcode.FullPostcode,
        AreaName = x.Postcode == null ? string.Empty : x.Postcode.Area == null ? string.Empty: x.Postcode.Area.Name,
        CityName = x.Postcode == null ? string.Empty : x.Postcode.Area == null ? string.Empty : x.Postcode.Area.City == null ? string.Empty:  x.Postcode.Area.City.Name,
        CountyName = x.Postcode == null ? string.Empty : x.Postcode.Area == null ? string.Empty : x.Postcode.Area.City == null ? string.Empty : x.Postcode.Area.City.County == null ?string.Empty: x.Postcode.Area.City.County.Name,
        CountryName= x.Postcode == null ? string.Empty : x.Postcode.Area == null ? string.Empty : x.Postcode.Area.City == null ? string.Empty : x.Postcode.Area.City.County == null ? string.Empty : x.Postcode.Area.City.County.Country == null ? string.Empty:x.Postcode.Area.City.County.Country.CountryName
        })
```

i need to replace this multi conditions with one condition for every property

Answer (score 3):

This is too complex for me to wrap my head around sorry :)

But what you need is the `?` and `??` operators. Second to last item in your really complex query will be like:

```
CountyName = x.Postcode?.Area?.City?.County?.Name ?? string.Empty
```

`x?.y` returns `y` if `x` is not `null` and returns `null` otherwise. If `y` is not `nullable` then result of `x?.y` will become `Nullable<T>` where `T` is `typeof(y)`

`x ?? y` returns `x` if `x` is not `null` and returns `y` if it is. Type of `x` and `y` should be the same here.
Hope it helps

**Edit**

In the second look I see that you are using LINQ with `IQueryable` which can't use the null propagating operator. So in this case you don't have this option you can either load all the data using a `ToList()` run your query on them if the data size is small. Or you can load each part in separate queries (which due to the number of sub element I don't recommend). Alternatively you can use tools like [this](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/wiki/NullPropagation)

My advice is the first option however may not be memory friendly on large datasets.

Sorry for the initial hasty answer.

Comment: Exception :-An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator



     `CountryName = x.Postcode?.Area?.City?.County?.Country?.CountryName ?? string.Empty`